MFC How to switch multiple CSplitterWnd in MainFrame
I want to switch multiple CSplitterWnd in MFC SDI project.
There are two CSplitterWnd members in CMainFrame.
CSplitterWnd m_wndSplitter;
CSplitterWnd2 m_wndSplitter2;

CSplitterWnd2 is derived from CSplitterWnd class.
And I created both splitters in CMainFrame::OnCreateClient like this:
BOOL CMainFrame::OnCreateClient(LPCREATESTRUCT /*lpcs*/,
    CCreateContext* pContext)
{
    m_wndSplitter.CreateStatic(this,1, 2);
    m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0,0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CSplitterWindowView), CSize(300,300), pContext);
    m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0,1, RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyView1), CSize(300,300), pContext);

    m_wndSplitter2.CreateStatic(this, 1, 2);
    m_wndSplitter2.CreateView(0, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyView2), CSize(300, 300), pContext);
    m_wndSplitter2.CreateView(0, 1, RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyView3), CSize(300, 300), pContext);

    return TRUE;
}

This is what the screen looks like when I run it:

it only shows m_wndSplitter2.
Now I want to switch to m_wndSplitter through the menu.
When I click the menu, the screen should be like this:

I tried ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) and ShowWindow(SW_SHOW) but it doesn't work.
void CMainFrame::OnMenuSplitter1() //menu event handler
{
    m_wndSplitter.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    m_wndSplitter2.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
}

The screen after call event handler was same as [showing m_wndSplitter2].

This does not work because what you want to hide are the panes/views instead of the splitters, which is what your last piece of code does.
To get the views you can use GetPane of the respective cell and then apply
the ->ShowWindow(...) logic to it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/csplitterwnd-class#getpane
